# Integration test with infinite loop

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, integration-testing

I need to run an integration test but having some issues, I know the first thing people are going to say which I have read in other answers is extract what is in the infinite loop to a method and test that, but it's not that simple as we are creating some stuff being used in the loop at runtime from a factory beforehand and I want to test the whole flow of the application via integration test.

```
while (true) {
    retrieveMessage();
}
```

I want to receive the one message I have sent and then exit (from the integration test only not from the running application when deployed).

I have thought about doing something like

```
if ("test".equals(getSpringActiveProfile()) {
   break;
}
```

But this would be bad practice would it writing into my codebase specifically for a test?

Any ideas or thoughts appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Because you don't need the infinite loop if you're going to _to receive the one message i have sent and then exit_  That's a contradiction.

Comment: I only want to do that from the integration test, when the application is running in deployed environment it needs to constantly poll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general a program should have a "natural" way to exit, infinite loops are a code smell per se... I would look for some approach like this:

```
boolean keepRunning = true; //even better as private field, then your class can get a "public void stop() { keepRunning = false; } method or something similar...
while(keepRunning) {
    //do whatever you need
}
```

This can be controlled by your test, and in the productive code, it can be used to kill the app when some kill-event arrives cleaning up everything...